# Which is the best LIDAR sensor to use Hector_mapping (Hector_slam)

Tags: slam, navigation, rplidar, hokuyo, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

In this opportunity I want to know which is the best option to use  and do SLAM with hector_mapping. I have 3 options:  Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 (10Hz), RPLidar (max 10Hz), Hokuyo UST-10LX Scanning Laser Rangefinder (40Hz).
I'm developing a project to merge OGMs (Occupancy Grid Map) from different robots, so I want to decide which is the best option to buy the best Lidar sensor. I know the importance of the Lidar scanning frequency to do SLAM and I know those sensors can do slam with hector_mapping, but those options differs in their prices. In fact, one Hokuyo UST10LX is equals to 5 RPLidar or 2 Hokuyo URG-04LX.

So, my question is, based on your wide and big expirience, **Hokuyo URG-04LX has a good performance doing slam with hector_slam?  RPLidar has a normal or good performance doing the same task?.**
I know Hokuyo UST-10LX is the best option for its specs (scanning frequency, over all) but I could get more robots with the others laser options. Take into account I don't care detection range, I just want to know is those options are enable for slam applications and do slam with hector_mapping.

Thank you in advance. I hope you can advise me.

Regards,
Carlos Velasquez
Colombia

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209303/which-is-the-best-lidar-sensor-to-use-hector_mapping-(hector_slam)/) by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A high frequency long range sensor is the best for hector mapping. A good eg. is the [Hokuyo URG 30 LX](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/utm_30lx.html). Although low frequency sensors can also work well. Eg. [Rplidar](http://www.robopeak.com/blog/?p=523) or [hokuyo urg 04lx](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/urg_04lx.html).  We have all the mentioned sensors in our lab. The UST 10  will probably be the best. I have extensively worked with URG 04LX and if you are building a small map with good features it will work without any troubles. rplidar although having a 360 range, i find it to be not so good for mapping. Although for localization all of them will work nicely. If your application is SLAM then choose the UST. And again for small area mapping (not a long loop closure) the other sensors will work fine.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on 2015-05-17**:
Thank you so much. It's the answer that I was expecting.  Thank you AlexR.  I just want to work in indoor environments and as I had written,  Im developing an application to merge maps from different robots,  so I need robots with short range but with good performance doing slam. Thank you :)

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-05-17**:
Glad that the answer helped. Please mark the comment as an answer by clicking on the check symbol.